# ColorFunction-> Distance to specific Point (Mean)

Tags: plotting, color

Good Day to you, 
I am trying to plot points in a ListPlot/ListPointPlot3D with a ColorFunktion representing the distance to a given point (in my case the Mean point of the data).
I have tried this, but its not returning a satisfying result.

```
    data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
ListPlot[data,
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {Mean[data[[All, 1]]], 
      Mean[data[[All, 2]]]}]]],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]
 ]
```

Current Result

[image: Current Result]

What I want

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments passed to the colour functions are rescaled to run between 0 and 1 by default. Disable this with

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

The colour function assumes inputs between 0 and 1 by default. Change this to a suitable range:

```
ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 3}}]
```

Tip: You could have used `Mean[data]`. Also, did you mean `Mean[ data[[All,2]] ]` when computing the 2nd coordinate?

Comment: Thank you for your help works like a charm.